# Accept GET request and rewrite POST requests

Tags: nginx

We have a restful service running in one of our server in port 8916. We decide to make the service available from the port 80 too. So, all of the requests are now passed to the port 8016. However, I'd like to show a help page in the case that the user access the service directly by a browser (GET). How can I send only the POST requests to the service, while we show the "index.html" when accessed by GET?

Here is our current NGINX configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ourserver.org;

        limit_conn alpha 3;
        limit_req  zone=delta burst=80 nodelay;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8916/;
            include proxy_params;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/indra-api.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/indra-api.error.log;

            client_max_body_size 8M;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use an `if` condition on the `$request_method` variable.

For example:

```
location / {
    if ($request_method != POST) { rewrite ^ /index.html last; }

    proxy_pass ...;
    ...
}
location = /index.html {
    root /path/to/html/files;
}
```

If your `index.html` file requires resources (css, images & js) from the same server, you may want to consider using a URI prefix. For example:

```
location / {
    if ($request_method != POST) { rewrite ^ /help/index.html last; }

    proxy_pass ...;
    ...
}
location /help/ {
    root /path/to/html/files;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`